# Is it possible to enable the “Force RLT Layout direction” developer option programmatically?

Tags: android

I've button in my application and what I want is that when the button is pressed it enables the "Force RLT Layout direction" option from developers option.

If there is any way to do it can someone provide me with that code ?

Comment: what will happen if developer mode is not unlocked?

Comment: While searching I found a code that checks if it's locked or unlocked. If not I guess it will unlock the developer mode however I haven't checked it yet.